# Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)

Tags: macros, starred-version

I would like to define a `*`'d version of a command, something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}{blah}
\newcommand{\foo*}{blahblah}
```

If I try to do this, LaTeX complains that I'm trying to redefine `\foo`, so I guess I need to do something special to handle `*`s. But what?

Comment: Of the different replies given: what is currently the recommended answer to this question?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

See [this entry](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cmdstar) in the TeX FAQ.

The "elegant" way is to use the [`suffix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/suffix) package (which requires eTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand\foo{blah}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\foo*{blahblah}

\begin{document}

\foo

\foo*

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this work with commands with optional arguments too? If so how?

Comment: @YAK I don't know. Note that the combination starred/optional is very rare.

Comment: Ups, I meant normal arguments, not optionals. And it works (`\WithSuffix\newcommand\foo*[1]{Foo #1}`) but warns "No 2nd argument following newcommand"...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant, and maybe the package has changed since then, but; \WithSuffix\newcommand\mycommand*[3]{starred command #1 #2 #3} works fine (\mycommand*{1}{2}{3})

Comment: Note that when using `\WithSuffix`, the name of the new command `\foo*` apparently cannot be surrounded by brackets `{...}` in the definition.

Answer (score 89):

If you look at [source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf) you might see a lot of lines that look like

```
\def\foo{\@ifstar\@foo\@@foo}
\def\@foo#1{...}
\def\@@foo#1{...}
```

This makes `\foo` a one-argument command that has regular and starred versions.  The starred version is the expansion of `\@foo` while the nonstarred version is that of `\@@foo`.  Using the @ sign in the auxiliary macros is a TeX convention which some authors embrace and some avoid.

There are higher-level ways to do it (as lockstep points out) but once you learn this pattern it's not too hard to use.  Just make sure it's between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` or in a `.sty` file.

**Edits** removed some inaccuracies and editorializing.

Comment: What's the controversy with `@`? FWIW, it's also used in Plain and ConTeXt (although far less in the latter, which `do` is more common, leading to some funny command names such as `\dodohideblock`).

Comment: Let me be clear that I follow the @-convention and am not advocating against it.  But I can also see the point of view that the name `\@foo` (or `\f@o` or `\f@@`) doesn't help the human reader understand the relationship.  `\@foowithstar` and `\@foowithoutstar` might be better.  Sorry if I blew that internal ambivalence into a controversy. :-)  Also, I wanted to point out that @'s are not *required* in auxiliary macros.

Comment: Yes, using '@' in place of vowels is a pain in the neck, whereas using it as a divider is fine.

Answer (score 81):

LaTeX3 solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF#1%
    {blahblah}% If a star is seen
    {blah}%     If no star is seen
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me when using `\dekotenize` in the command *and* invoking the command from the caption of a lstlisting.