# \autoref does not capitalize initial character in sentence when referencing label in listings environment

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, capitalization

I have defined the following

```
\providecommand*{\lstnumberautorefname}{line}
```

and within my text

```
\begin{lstlisting} 
            |\label{sdd_1}|<sqlCallStatistics>YES</sqlCallStatistics>
\end{lstlisting}
```

When I now use in my text

```
xxx. \autoref{sdd_1}
```

then I receive the following output :

```
xxxx. line 1
```

instead of (what I had expected)

```
xxxx. Line 1
```

Comment: Why would you expect an upper case "L" when defining `\lstnumberautorefname` with a lower case "l"?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: True, I guess "capitalization" should refer to "auto capitalization".

Comment: @Werner: As far as I know, `\autoref` doesn't do "auto capitalization".

Comment: Yes, that's true. You have to manually alter it to accommodate this, which almost defeats the purpose of "auto"-`\ref`-ing it.

Comment: Well, this may be a rather awkward solution, but would it not be possible to create an `\Autoref` macro, which will locally redefine all of the `\somethingautorefname`s to a capitalized version? (Or, alternatively, just the one for the autoref target?)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 52):

`\autoref` doesn't do automatic capitalization, as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand*{\lstnumberautorefname}{line}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\autoref{sec:test} and a period before the reference. \autoref{sec:test}
\begin{lstlisting} [escapeinside=||,numbers=left]
      <sqlCallStatistics>YES</sqlCallStatistics>|\label{sdd_1}|
\end{lstlisting}

\autoref{sdd_1}  and a period before the reference. \autoref{sdd_1}

\end{document}
```

You could use the `cleveref` package to have `\cref` (for lower case) and `\Cref` (for upper case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting} [escapeinside=||,numbers=left]
      <sqlCallStatistics>YES</sqlCallStatistics>|\label{sdd_1}|
\end{lstlisting}

\cref{sdd_1}  and a period before the reference. \Cref{sdd_1}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** As `MWin123` commented: By default `\cref` turns only the number "1" into a hyperlink, while `\autoref` makes the whole "line 1" a clickable link. Fortunately there's an option `nameinlink` for it, i.e., you can use `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}`

Comment: By default `\cref` turns only the number "1" into a hyperlink, while `\autoref` makes the whole "line 1" a clickable link. Fortunately there's an option `nameinlink` for it, i.e., you can use `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}`.

Answer (score 20):

There is no easy way around this, without going as far as to redefine `\lstnumberautorefname` to `Line` or including additional packages. To that extent, you might just as well be better off using

```
\hyperref[sdd_1]{Line~\ref*{sdd_1}}
```

without having to resort to the other methods. This will provide the same linkage, but capitalized. `\ref*` works just like `\ref` but does not include a hyperlink. The hyperlink is provided by `\hyperref[<label>]{<stuff>}`. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{numbers=left,escapeinside=||}
\providecommand*{\lstnumberautorefname}{line}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting} 
|\label{sdd_1}|<sqlCallStatistics>YES</sqlCallStatistics>
\end{lstlisting}
Here is some text. \hyperref[sdd_1]{Line~\ref*{sdd_1}} is important, and so is \autoref{sdd_1}.
\end{document}​
```

Comment: It's sad that `autoref` cannot take start of lines into account (possibly by taking an extra parameter for an arbitrary string to insert, if not possible to work automatically), but your `hyperref` trick works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is mentioned in [the manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html).

Use:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\addto\extrasenglish{  
  \def\typeautorefname{Type}  
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

If you want to capitalize usage of `\autoref` or want to completely rename the auto-reference name. Just replace `type` with the type of reference, so `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, etc..

E.g.:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Subsection}
}
```

I realize this does not meet your requirement of defining a `\Autoref` command. However, I thought it would be worth mentioning since it's a cleaner version, might fulfill someone-else's requirements and it took me a while to find something that actually works.

Comment: I think OP wants "Line" at the beginning of a sentence, but "line" elsewhere.  Just (re)defining `(type)autorefname` would make it always capitalized.

Comment: @Teepeemm I assumed the same. Since OP specified the desire for a `\Autoref` command. However, I thought it would still be worth mentioning.

Comment: You're both correct. This is not exactly what the OP has asked for. Yet, for other people stambling across this thread (e.g. me) it might be useful. I therefore see it as a constructive contribution to the thread.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a way to get `\Autoref` from *hyperref* package. Heiko Oberdiek (the maintainer of the package) will provide a package solution in due course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\def\figureautorefname{figure}
\def\tableautorefname{table}
\def\Autoref#1{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\reserved@a{\cpttrimspaces{#1}}%
  \ifcsndefTF{r@#1}{%
    \xaftercsname{\expandafter\testreftype\@fourthoffive}
      {r@\reserved@a}.\\{#1}%
  }{%
    \ref{#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\def\testreftype#1.#2\\#3{%
  \ifcsndefTF{#1autorefname}{%
    \def\reserved@a##1##2\@nil{%
      \uppercase{\def\ref@name{##1}}%
      \csn@edef{#1autorefname}{\ref@name##2}%
      \autoref{#3}%
    }%
    \reserved@a#1\@nil
  }{%
    \autoref{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Example:
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\def\withop#1#2{With \texttt{\string#1}: #1{#2}\par}
\section{Test section}
\parindent0pt
\label{xx}
\withop\autoref{xx}
\withop\Autoref{xx}

\subsection{Test subsection}
\label{yy}
\withop\autoref{yy}
\withop\Autoref{yy}
\withop\autoref{tab:1}
\withop\Autoref{tab:1}
\withop\autoref{fig:1}
\withop\Autoref{fig:1}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Sample table}\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
...&...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!h]
...
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As of fall 2013 the current hyperref version is from 2012-11-06 (6.83m) and does not feature an `\Autoref` AFAICS. Where did he say to provide one in the future or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: This works well with the default autoref names, but I have problems with custom names. Example: adding `\def\subsectionautorefname{myprettyname}` after the `\begin{document}` line will make the lower case autoref show `myprettyname` but the upper case Autoref `Subsection`. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @ahmed-musa Is there an easy way to define a starred version of this macro to use it in the command defined in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands-macro is based on the `\newcommand` command, not on `\def`.

Comment: @KlausKopec Have you meanwhile found a fix for the problem you describe?

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger I have not resolved this. Sorry that I cannot be of more help.

Comment: Does not appear to work any more ("Extra `\endgroup`" error message).

Answer (score 2):

A simple hacky way is to add the following

```
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Table}
\renewcommand{\partautorefname}{Part}
\renewcommand{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
```

Right before your

```
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

The quickest way that I found, without replace by `\cref` in the entire document (as it was shown and suggested in previous answers) was to implement the following lines below of `\usepackage{hyperref}` to capitalize the chapter word:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{
    \def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}
}
```

It's mandatory to include `\usepackage[english]{babel}` if you don't have it. I found this information on https://github.com/Cryptosaurus/iacrtrans/issues/9

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify how your answer solves the OP's query, which was about uppercasing "list" in a cross-reference.

Comment: This was already mentioned in more detail in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460952/123129) by Byebye.