# \nameref -- How to display section name AND its number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering

Is it possible to make `\nameref` display not only the title of the section but also its number?

```
\section{First Section}
\label{sec:some_sec}

\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\label{sec:subsec}

[...]

As we defined in section \nameref{sec:some_sec}, yada yada yada, see section \nameref{sec:subsec}
```

With normal `\nameref` I get:

> "As we defined in section First Section, yada yada yada, see section Unnumbered subsection"

what I want is a combination of numbers (as in `\autoref`} and section names AND (if possible) unnumbered subsections should inherit the number of the parenting section:

> "As we defined in section 1 First Section, yada yada yada, see section 1 Unnumbered subsection"

Comment: `section~\ref{sec:some_sec} \nameref{sec:some_sec}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your label `{sec:subsec}` has a negative effect. You are using `\subsection*` and so there is no anchor (number) for any label.

Comment: Marco, the answer works as I described above. For un-numbered subsections the number of the parenting section should be used -- and this is the case. Also, when i click the text in the PDF I get to the subsection (as expected). Thats exactly what I wanted ;)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

How about defining a new command `\fullref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

% Original definition
% \newcommand\fullref[1]{\autoref{#1} \nameref{#1}} % Two links

% Updated definition, see explanation below
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}} % One single link

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\label{sec:some_sec}

\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\label{sec:subsec}

[...]

As we defined in \fullref{sec:some_sec}, yada yada yada, see \fullref{sec:subsec}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

The `\fullref` defined above produces two links, one by `\autoref`, the other by `\nameref`. Heiko Oberdiek suggests the following definition that combines the two into one single link:

```
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
```

Comment: You get a full link in one piece by `\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref{#1}}}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks :-) Your suggestion is incorporated.

Comment: I have added the star for `\nameref` that I have forgotten in the comment. The star forms prevent nested double links.

Comment: Don't you need to add \usepackage{nameref} for this to work?

Comment: @for3st: I don't think so.

Comment: It conflicts with the `titlesec` package. The reference prints things like "chapter 2" instead of the name of the section.

Comment: `tcolorbox` does many things and, being fully compatible with `hyperref`, also includes using `\cref{exp:5-1}` to refer to `Example 5-3`, `\cref{3-0}` to `chapter 3 \label{3-0}`, `\cref{5-3}` to `chapter 5 section 3 \label{3-5}`. I just tried `\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\cref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}` which makes the whole thing clickable. But, as I prefer (as with \cref) the words `chapter` and `section` *not* to appear in the link, I regretfully reverted to having to type, e.g. `\cref{1-0} \nameref{1-0} on page \pageref{1-1}` and `\cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1} on page \pageref{1-1}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek if I want to capitalize the first letter, can I use `\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}` with `cleveref` package or is there a better way?

Comment: @HerrK. if I only section 1 and section is Section 1, how can I set my tex file?

Comment: hyperref's `sectionautorefname` can be set empty to avoid the name `section' to appear. The hyperref manual contains such an example.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with @herr-k 's answer,  I went a step farther and defined four (4) new commands: `\secref`, `\subsecref`, `\subsubsecref`, and `\parref`.

```
\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{Specification \ref*{#1}, \nameref*{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\subsecref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{Section \ref*{#1}, \nameref*{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsecref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{Section , \nameref*{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\parref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{Section \ref*{#1}, \nameref*{#1}}}
```

Doing so allows me to customize how the hyperlink text displays for each level of my document.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `section` in link text: change the `\autoref` to `\ref`.

I.e.: `\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\ref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}} % One single link`