# Display reference name, label number and target name with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to reference a section with `cleveref` like in the following example:

```
\section{Foobar}
\label{sec:foobar}

See \cref{sec:foobar}.
```

The output of this is:

> See section 1.

But what I would like is this:

> See section 1 Foobar.

I understand that there is no command by default, that produces this output.

So I tried to build my own command like suggested for the `hyperref` package in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number). However, I could not find an equivalent command to `hyperref`'s `\nameref` in `cleveref`'s documentation.

Is it possible to create a new command, that produces my desired output?

Comment: You can just load `hyperref` and use its `\nameref` command on top of `cleveref`.

Comment: @sfat What about Andrew's suggestion? Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it is. Quite comfortabily actually, as I've been using hyperref anyway. I think this could be posted as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `@AndrewSwann`'s suggestion, I created a command, that makes use of both `cleveref`'s `\Cref` and `hyperref`'s `\nameref`:

```
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
```

The benefit compared to the solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number), which only uses `hyperref`, is that the use of `\Cref` allows for capitalized reference names.

Both `\Cref` and `\nameref` create a single link. Encapsulating them in `\hyperref` merges them to a single link.

Comment: With regard  to the query you posted originally, what is the instruction `\hyperref[{#1}]` inside the `\fullref` macro supposed to achieve?

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify `\hyperref`'s intent.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the `\hyperref[]{}` instruction does.