# Cref an algorithm with its caption

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms, cleveref, algorithm2e

When I \cref an algorithm, it shows "algorithm 1". Is it possible to ref an algorithm with its numbering and caption? Like "algorithm 1 foo", where "foo" is the caption of algorithm 1. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132762.