# problem with starred version of \nameref, \autoref, \fullref from hyperref with tex4ht

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, html, make4ht

EDIT:@runartrollet: I clarify  the problem. THe pdf outputs as expected the links in every instance of the commands `autoref` and `nameref`. and`\fullref`, starred or not. But the `html` file, the command

- `fullref without star` has no underlined link for the title of the section
  [whereas the non-starred `autoref` and `nameref` individually behaves well]
- `fullref with star` does link-ify the `chapitre+section number+section title`, but it is does not replace the `label` of the section with the actual `title of the section`
- `nameref` without star does not work in html

=================================================

I have a problem with `hyperref+make4ht` when I use `autoref` and `nameref`. I use a command `\fullref` found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number/121871#121871).

compiled with `make4ht -ul hello.tex`, my output is 
[image: html output]
[image: pdf output]

the problem comes from the `star` after `\nameref`:

```
this is a comment from the page above:

I have added the star for \nameref that I have forgotten in the comment. The star forms prevent nested double links. – Heiko Oberdiek Jun 30 '13 at 23:32
```

We see that my `label` `MYLABEL` is not always taken by `make4ht`

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%\usepackage{alternative4ht}
%%%\altusepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{hyperref}
%%% for babel
%\addto\extrasenglish{\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation~(#1)\null}}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{%
  Equation~(#1)\null
}
\def\sectionautorefname{chapitre}
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref{#1}...\nameref{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\fullrefwithstar}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1}...\nameref*{#1}}}


\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents


fullref without star: \fullref{sec:MYLABEL},\\
autoref without star : \autoref{MYLABEL}\\
nameref without star : \nameref{sec:MYLABEL}\\
ref: \ref{MYLABEL}\\

\section{Excellences...}\label{sec:MYLABEL}\label{MYLABEL}

fullref with star: \fullrefwithstar{sec:MYLABEL},\\
autoref with star : \autoref*{sec:MYLABEL}\\
nameref with star : \nameref*{sec:MYLABEL}\\
ref with star: \ref*{sec:MYLABEL}\\



\end{document}
```

Comment: I am unsure what you feel is the problem here. Maybe I am just overlooking it. What result are you expecting?

Comment: and why do you have two labels for the section?

Answer (score 2):

*edit*: I've posted a [patch at tex4ht bug tracker](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?269), it should be fixed in TeX Live soon.

---

There is missing support for `\nameref*` command in `tex4ht` configuration file `hyperref.4ht`, it seems. Missing `\@namerefstar` command is reported during compilation. This is strange, as `tex4ht` does normally support commands defined in packages out of the box, it needs to configure only commands where we need specific formatting usually. The culprit is that `hyperref.sty` detects `tex4ht` and it stops it's own loading before the command is defined.
Anyway, we can just copy definition of this command from `hyperref.sty` at suitable place in `hyperref.4ht`:

```
\def\@namerefstar#1{%                                                
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@thirdoffive  
}
```

The full `hyperref.4ht` is now following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% hyperref.4ht                          2016-01-12-20:20 %
% Copyright (C) 1999-2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
% Copyright 2009-2016 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\csname end:hyperref\endcsname
\@ifpackageloaded{nameref}{}
{
   \let\sv:label\label
   \RequirePackage{nameref}%
   \let\label\sv:label
   \input nameref.4ht
}

\expandafter\ifx \csname ifHy@texht\endcsname\relax
   \expand:after{\expandafter
      \let \csname ifHy@texht\endcsname}\csname ifhy@texht\endcsname
\fi
\expandafter\ifx \csname ifHy@texht\endcsname\relax
   \expand:after{\expandafter
      \let \csname ifHy@texht\endcsname}\csname iffalse\endcsname
\fi
\ifHy@texht \else
    \:warning{tex4ht loaded after hyperref}
    \csname Hy@texhttrue\endcsname
\fi

\def\auto@setref#1#2#3{\@safe@activestrue
   \let\:autoref\::autoref
\T@ref{#3}\@safe@activesfalse}
\ifx\@refstar\:UnDef
  \def\@refstar{\let\:autoref\:gobble
\T@ref}
\fi
\def\:temp{\protect \T@ref}
\ifx \::ref\:temp
   \edef\::ref{\noexpand\protect \expandafter\noexpand \csname ::ref \endcsname}
   \expandafter\def\csname ::ref \endcsname{\@ifstar \@refstar \T@ref}
\fi
\def\:temp#1{\@safe@activestrue\org@:ref{#1}\@safe@activesfalse}
\expandafter\ifx \csname :ref \endcsname\:temp
   \expandafter\def\csname :ref \endcsname{\@ifnextchar*{\:refstar}{\r:ref}}
   \def\r:ref#1{\@safe@activestrue\org@:ref{#1}\@safe@activesfalse}
   \def\:refstar#1{\r:ref}
\fi

\expandafter\ifx \csname real@setref\endcsname\relax
   \def\@pagerefstar#1{%
      \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@secondoffive
   }
   \def\@namerefstar#1{%
       \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@thirdoffive
     }
   \def\HyRef@StarSetRef#1{%
     \begingroup
       \Hy@safe@activestrue
       \edef\x{#1}%
       \@onelevel@sanitize\x
       \edef\x{\endgroup
         \noexpand\HyRef@@StarSetRef
           \expandafter\noexpand\csname r@\x\endcsname{\x}%
       }%
     \x
   }

   \def\HyRef@@StarSetRef#1#2#3{%
     \ifx#1\@undefined
       \let#1\relax
     \fi
     \real@setref#1#3{#2}%
   }
\fi
\expandafter\ifx \csname real@setref\endcsname\relax
   \let\real@setref\@setref
\fi



\DeclareRobustCommand*{\autoref}{%
  \@ifstar{\HyRef@autoref\@gobbletwo}{\HyRef@autoref\hyper@@link}%
}
\def\HyRef@autoref#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \expandafter\HyRef@autosetref\csname r@#2\endcsname{#2}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\autopageref}{%
  \@ifstar{%
    \HyRef@autopagerefname\pageref*%
  }\HyRef@autopageref
}
\def\HyRef@autopageref#1{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{\HyRef@autopagerefname\pageref*{#1}}%
}
\def\HyRef@autopagerefname{%
  \@ifundefined{pageautorefname}{%
    \@ifundefined{pagename}{%
      \Hy@Warning{No autoref name for `page'}%
    }{%
      \pagename\nobreakspace
    }%
  }{%
    \pageautorefname\nobreakspace
  }%
}

\def\HyRef@autosetref#1#2#3{% link command, csname, refname
  \HyRef@ShowKeysRef{#2}%
  \ifcase 0\ifx#1\relax 1\fi\ifx#1\Hy@varioref@undefined 1\fi\relax
    \edef\HyRef@thisref{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }%
    \expandafter\HyRef@testreftype\HyRef@thisref.\\%
    \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    #3{%
      \expandafter\@fifthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \HyRef@currentHtag
      \expandafter\@firstoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
      \null
    }%
  \else
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#2' on page \thepage\space undefined%
    }%
  \fi
}

\def\HyRef@testreftype#1.#2\\{%
  \@ifundefined{#1autorefname}{%
    \@ifundefined{#1name}{%
      \HyRef@StripStar#1\\*\\\@nil{#1}%
      \@ifundefined{\HyRef@name autorefname}{%
        \@ifundefined{\HyRef@name name}{%
          \def\HyRef@currentHtag{}%
          \Hy@Warning{No autoref name for `#1'}%
        }{%
          \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname\HyRef@name name\endcsname
            \noexpand~%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
          \expandafter\noexpand\csname\HyRef@name autorefname\endcsname
          \noexpand~%
        }%
      }%
    }{%
      \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1name\endcsname
        \noexpand~%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1autorefname\endcsname
      \noexpand~%
    }%
  }%
}

\def\HyRef@StripStar#1*\\#2\@nil#3{%
  \def\HyRef@name{#2}%
  \ifx\HyRef@name\HyRef@CaseStar
    \def\HyRef@name{#1}%
  \else
    \def\HyRef@name{#3}%
  \fi
}
\def\HyRef@CaseStar{*\\}
\def\HyRef@currentHtag{}
\let\HyRef@ShowKeysRef\@gobble
\providecommand*\AMSautorefname{\equationautorefname}
\providecommand*\Hfootnoteautorefname{\footnoteautorefname}
\providecommand*\Itemautorefname{\itemautorefname}
\providecommand*\itemautorefname{item}
\providecommand*\equationautorefname{Equation}
\providecommand*\footnoteautorefname{footnote}
\providecommand*\itemautorefname{item}
\providecommand*\figureautorefname{Figure}
\providecommand*\tableautorefname{Table}
\providecommand*\partautorefname{Part}
\providecommand*\appendixautorefname{Appendix}
\providecommand*\chapterautorefname{chapter}
\providecommand*\sectionautorefname{section}
\providecommand*\subsectionautorefname{subsection}
\providecommand*\subsubsectionautorefname{subsubsection}
\providecommand*\paragraphautorefname{paragraph}
\providecommand*\subparagraphautorefname{subparagraph}
\providecommand*\FancyVerbLineautorefname{line}
\providecommand*\theoremautorefname{Theorem}
\providecommand*\pageautorefname{page}

\expandafter\ifx \csname H@item\endcsname\relax
   \def\:temp{dvi}\ifx \XR@ext\:temp \else
     \def\:temp{html}\ifx \XR@ext\:temp \else
         \:warning{\string\usepackage[...]{hyperref} assumes `\XR@ext'
              option, not `tex4ht'}
   \fi\fi
\else
      \:warning{\string\usepackage[...]{hyperref} assumes `\XR@ext'
           option, not `tex4ht'}
\fi

\ifx \@@wrindex\:UnDef \else
   \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
     \protected@write\@indexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}%
     \endgroup \@esphack
   }
\fi
\ifx \HyInd@@wrindex\:UnDef \else
   \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{\HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2}}%
\fi
\ifx \Hy@RestoreLastskip\:UnDef
   \let\Hy@RestoreLastskip\relax
\fi
\def\hyperlink#1#2{\Link{#1}{}#2\EndLink}
\def\hypertarget#1#2{\Link{}{#1}#2\EndLink}
\ifx \hyperpage\:UnDef  \let\hyperpage=\empty  \fi
\def\:temp#12->#2//{\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp\meaning\setkeys2->//
\ifx\:temp\empty \else
   \pend:defII\setkeys{%
      \expandafter\ifx \csname ##1:keys\endcsname\relax
             \expandafter\def\csname ##1:keys\endcsname{##2}%
      \else  \expandafter\append:def\csname ##1:keys\endcsname{##2}%
      \fi  }
\fi
\def\:choices#1,#2//#3#4{%
   \def\AttributeVal{#1}#3\AttributeVal#4%
   \def\:temp{#2}\ifx \:temp\empty \else
   \def\:temp{\:choices#2//{#3}{#4}}\expandafter\:temp\fi}
\def\check:args#1=#2//{\def\:temp{#2}}
\def\arg:quote#1=#2//{%
   \del:sp#1//%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:\:form:attr ::\nosp:arg\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\ifx \csname a:::\nosp:arg\endcsname\relax
            \:warning{No configuration for \:form:attr ::\nosp:arg}%
      \else \def\AttributeVal{#2}\csname a:::\nosp:arg\endcsname
      \fi
   \else
      \def\AttributeVal{#2}\csname a:\:form:attr ::\nosp:arg\endcsname
   \fi
   }
\def\del:sp#1#2//{\def\nosp:arg{#1#2}}
\def\:form:attr{\ifx\:textarea\empty
   \default:textarea\else \:textarea\fi}
\def\scan:args#1{\let\Attributes=\empty \let\:textarea=\empty
   \expandafter\ifx \csname #1:keys\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\scan:arg
   \else  \expand:after{\expand:after
      {\expandafter\scan:arg}\csname #1:keys\endcsname,}\fi
}
\def\scan:arg#1,#2//{%
   \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \:temp\empty\else \ifx \:temp\space\else
      \check:args#1=//%
      \ifx \:temp\empty
         \edef\:textarea{\ifx \:textarea\empty\else ,\fi #1}%
      \else
         \arg:quote#1//%
   \fi\fi\fi
   \def\:temp{#2}\ifx \:temp\empty \else
   \def\:temp{\scan:arg#2//}\expandafter\:temp\fi
}
\def\check:type#1{\:Optionfalse
   \def\:temp{#1}\expandafter\check:t\:textarea,//}%
\def\check:t#1,#2//{\def\:tempa{#1}\ifx \:temp\:tempa \:Optiontrue
   \else
       \def\:tempa{#2}\ifx\:tempa\empty\else \def\:tempa{\check:t#2//}\fi
       \expandafter\:tempa
   \fi}

\def\Hy@MakeCurrentHref#1{%
  \edef\HyperLocalCurrentHref{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\HyperLocalCurrentHref
  \global\let\HyperGlobalCurrentHref\HyperLocalCurrentHref
  \let\HyperLocalCurrentHref\HyperGlobalCurrentHref
  \ifHy@localanchorname
    \let\@currentHref\HyperLocalCurrentHref
  \else
    \global\let\@currentHref\HyperGlobalCurrentHref
  \fi
}

\let\Hy@SectionAnchorHref\@gobble
\newlength\Hy@SectionHShift

\def\Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto#1{%
  \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHref{#1.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
}

\def\hyper@makecurrent#1{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\Hy@param{#1}%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring
      \let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp
    \fi
    \ifHy@hypertexnames
      \let\@number\@firstofone
      \@ifundefined{latin@Alph}{}{%
        \ifx\@Alph\greek@Alph
          \def\@Alph{Alph\@arabic}%
        \fi
      }%
      \ifHy@naturalnames
        \let\textlatin\@firstofone
        \xdef\@currentHlabel{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \else
        \xdef\@currentHlabel{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      \xdef\@currentHref{%
        \Hy@param.\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@currentHlabel
      }%
    \else
      \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter
      \xdef\@currentHref{\Hy@param.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\def\hyper@natlinkend{%
  \hyper@linkend
}
\def\hyper@linkurl#1#2{%
  \leavevmode  \begingroup    \hyper@chars
   \ifx \hyper:normalise\:UnDef
      \expandafter\pend:defI\expandafter\:autoref
                            \expandafter{\HyRef@currentHtag}%
      \let\HyRef@currentHtag\empty
      \Hy@colorlink{\@urlcolor}#1\Hy@endcolorlink
    \else
      \Link[#2]{}{}\Hy@colorlink{\@urlcolor}#1\Hy@endcolorlink\EndLink
      \global\let\hyper:normalise\:UnDef
    \fi
  \endgroup }
\AtBeginDocument{%
%  \pend:defI\hyper@normalise{\let\hyper:normalise\def}%
  \expandafter\pend:def\csname hyperref
                     \endcsname{\let\hyper:normalise\def}%
  \expandafter\pend:def\csname href \endcsname{\let\hyper:normalise\def}%
  \pend:defI\T@ref{\edef\RefArg{##1}}}
\def\label@hyperref[#1]#2{{%
   \def\hyperrefLabel{#2}%
   \Configure{ref}
     {\Link}{\EndLink}{\Configure{ref}{}{}{}#2}\ref{#1}}}
\Configure{@newlabel}{\@onelevel@sanitize\@currentlabelname}
\append:def\protect:wrtoc{\def\ref{\protect\o:ref}}

\ifx \H@equation\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:equation:\H@equation
\fi
\ifx \H@endequation\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:endequation:\H@endequation
\fi
\ifx \H@eqnarray\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:eqnarray:\H@eqnarray
\fi
\ifx \H@endsubeqnarray\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:endsubeqnarray:\H@endsubeqnarray
\fi
\ifx \H@subeqnarray\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:subeqnarray:\H@subeqnarray
\fi
\ifx \H@endsubeqnarray\:UnDef \else
   \let\o:endsubeqnarray:\H@endsubeqnarray
\fi


\csname ReadBookmarks\endcsname
\ifx \Hy@linkfileprefix\empty\else
   \:warning{\noexpand\href of hyperref.sty introduces the prefix
             `\Hy@linkfileprefix' to prefix-free references.
             The command \string\hyperlinkfileprefix{...}
             may be used for changing the prefix (probably
             \string\hyperlinkfileprefix{}).}
\fi
\def\hyper@linkfile#1#2#3{\Link[#2]{#3}{}#1\EndLink}
\def\phantomsection{%
 \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter
 \xdef\@currentHref{likesection.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
 \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
\catcode`\:=12
\def\@hyper@readexternallink#1#2#3#4:#5:#6\\#7{%
      \hyper@linkurl{#3}{#7\ifx\\#2\\\else\##2\fi}}
\catcode`\:=11
\def\@Form[#1]{%
   \def\default:textarea{Form}%
   \scan:args{}#1,//\a:Form }
                                        \def\@endForm{\b:Form}
                                         \NewConfigure{Form}{2}
\def\@TextField[#1]#2{%
   \def\default:textarea{TextField}%
   \scan:args{Field}#1,//%
   \csname a:TextField::\:textarea\endcsname  \leavevmode#2%
   \csname b:TextField::\:textarea\endcsname  }
\def\@PushButton[#1]#2{%
   \def\default:textarea{PushButton}%
   \scan:args{}#1,value=#2,//%
   \csname a:PushButton::\:textarea\endcsname }
\def\@Reset[#1]#2{%
   \def\default:textarea{Reset}%
   \scan:args{}#1,value=#2,//%
   \csname a:Reset::\:textarea\endcsname }
\def\@Submit[#1]#2{%
   \def\default:textarea{Submit}%
   \scan:args{}#1,value=#2,//%
   \csname a:Submit::\:textarea\endcsname }
\def\@CheckBox[#1]#2{%
   \def\default:textarea{CheckBox}%
   \scan:args{}#1,//%
   \csname a:CheckBox::\:textarea\endcsname
   #2\csname b:CheckBox::\:textarea\endcsname}
\def\@ChoiceMenu[#1]#2#3{%
   \def\default:textarea{ChoiceMenu}%
   \scan:args{}#1,//%
   \csname a:ChoiceMenu::\:textarea\endcsname  \leavevmode#2%
   \csname b:ChoiceMenu::\:textarea\endcsname
   \:choices  #3,//{\csname d:ChoiceMenu::\:textarea\endcsname}%
         {\csname e:ChoiceMenu::\:textarea\endcsname}%
   \csname c:ChoiceMenu::\:textarea\endcsname }

\def\hyper@linkstart#1#2{%
  \expandafter\Hy@colorlink\expandafter{\csname @#1color\endcsname}%
  \def\Hy@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\Hy@tempa\@urltype
    \Link[#2]{}{}%
  \else
    {\hyper@chars\ifx\rel:hyper\def\Link{#2}{}\else\Link[\##2]{}{}\fi}%
  \fi  \global\let\rel:hyper=\:UnDef
}
\def\hyper@linkend{%
  \EndLink
  \Hy@endcolorlink
}
\def\hyper@anchorstart#1{%
  \Hy@SaveLastskip
  \begingroup
    \hyper@chars\Link{}{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \Hy@activeanchortrue
}
\def\hyper@anchorend{%
  \EndLink
  \Hy@activeanchorfalse
  \Hy@RestoreLastskip
}
\def\hyper@anchor#1{\hyper@anchorstart{#1}\hyper@anchorend}

\expandafter\ifx\csname ifHy@hyperindex\endcsname\relax
\else \Hy@hyperindexfalse
\fi
\Hinput{hyperref}
\endinput
```

and this is a result when we compile your document:

[image]