# Redefine \autoref for paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, ref, autoref, nameref

I'm working with `\autoref` from the `hyperref` package to reference my sections, etc.

What I currently work with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\paragraphautorefname}{Paragraph}%
}
```

As my `secnumdepth` uses the default value my paragraphs are not numbered. Therefore, I'm currently using

```
\autoref{example} (\nameref{example})
```

to reference my paragraphs. I could obviously write a command for that but would have to change it in case I restructure my document (which somehow goes against the idea of `autoref`).

I wondered whether it would be possible to change the behavior of the `\autoref` command to something like the above depending on the `secnumdepth` counter, i.e. for all unnumbered sections (I'm never referencing starred sections line `\section*`).

As I have no idea how I would do that, my only idea was to redefine the `\paragraphautorefname` command like so

```
\def\paragraphautorefname~#1\null{%
  Section~#1 (<paragraphname>)\null
}
```

but I don't know how to access the paragraph's name there.

Any thoughts on this? Is there an easier way I'm not seeing?

Edit: To clarify the outcome I'm lookig for.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\paragraphautorefname}{Paragraph}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{cha:1}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}\label{sub:1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}\label{subsub:1}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}\label{par:1}

\section{Another Section}
Here I can happily reference \autoref{cha:1}, \autoref{sec:1}, \autoref{sub:1}, and \autoref{subsub:1}.

If I'm trying to reference the paragraph, as expected, I will get the result of the next enclosing numbered section \autoref{par:1}.

I want that \verb|\autoref| applied to \texttt{par:1} outputs something like \verb|\nameref{par:1} (\autoref{par:1})| would, so: \nameref{par:1} (\autoref{par:1}), without me doing that manually.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the MWE above]

Comment: The `\fullref` command here will do exactly what you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121871/172926 (just put some parentheses around the `\nameref*`).

Comment: Sorry if that was not completely clear: I want to automatically do that when using `\autoref` but, if and only if the referenced section is not numbered. The `\autoref` command should have different outputs -- I do not want the name of the section if it is numbered.