# How can I make hyperref stop thinking there are undefined references?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering, cleveref, warnings

I am using my variation of the `\fullref` command from the question [\nameref -- How to display section name AND its number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number), my one is called `\typeref`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand*{\typeref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref{#1}}} % One single link
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref{#1}: \nameref{#1}}} % One single link

\begin{document}
\typeref{firstlabel}.

\typeref{secondlabel}.

\typeref{firstlabel,secondlabel}.

\cleardoublepage
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{firstlabel}
    Figure 1
\end{figure}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{secondlabel}
    Figure 2
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which correctly generated the PDF file:

[image]

But when compiling this, hyperref keeps popping the warning every time I compile/recompile the PDF:

```
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `firstlabel,secondlabel' on page 1 undefined on
input line 15.

[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2] [3]
[4] [5] (test3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

How can I make `hyperref` stop thinking there are undefined references?

Comment: why are you using the `\hyperref` command? cleveref is hyperref aware, `\newcommand*{\typeref}[1]{\Cref{#1}}` works on its own.

Comment: I though I had to use because I would like the hyperref link to include the element name `Figure` and the number `1`, not only the number `1` and on the [original  question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number), they said this: **The `\fullref` defined above produces two links, one by `\autoref`, the other by `\nameref`. Heiko Oberdiek suggests the following definition that combines the two into one single link: ``\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}``**;

Comment: your example doesn't use \fullref.

Comment: It is because my `\fullref` is broken as it uses `\nameref`, and `\nameref` only accepts a single argument. But I opened this other question to fix it and use a custom `\nameref` which support several labels: [Undefined control sequence while adding a new parameter to a existing \ExplSyntaxOn code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515877/undefined-control-sequence-while-adding-a-new-parameter-to-a-existing-explsynta)