# Cleveref refuses to find references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, capitalization, autoref

Ok, so I have a document where I made use of `\autoref`.

I've been told now, that we want all `chapter`s, `section`s, `subsection`s, etc. capitalised.

Since there is no `\Autoref` and I couldn't get its implementation from

[\autoref does not capitalize initial character in sentence when referencing label in listings environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34155/autoref-does-not-capitalize-initial-character-in-sentence-when-referencing-labe)

to work, I tried going with another answer therein and replaced all `\autoref{foo}` instructions with `\Cref{foo}` from the `cleveref` package.

But now all references show up as `??`.

I'm use the `memoir` document class and texmaker, I run

```
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

and I compile the document with Texmaker's

```
PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + show PDF
```

command.

How do I make `\Cref` work?

Comment: Did you load `cleveref` *after* `hyperref`?

Comment: @Bernard I did not, actually. Thank you. Want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: That's not necessary, there's already a number of answers which mention it. Did it solve your problem?