# How do I write a starred macro?

Tags: macros, starred-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining starred versions of commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands)

I want to write a macro that has a starred version, e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\blah}{{\bfseries blah}}
\newcommand*{\blah*}{{\itshape blah}}
```

but when I do that I get an error: "Command already defined"

I looked through latex.ltx, but couldn't figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill - thanks for pointing that out. When I typed in the question in the title several other questions were offered as possible duplicates, or at least places where the answer might be, but the one you listed wasn't one of them. It's amusing that this question is almost an exact duplicate of mine, right down to using 'blah' in a newcommand. Lastly, this was answered in less than 5 mins after I asked it. I love this place.