# Asterisk inside a variable

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am trying to define a variable with an asterisk in its value but keep getting errors. I have tried `\def`, `\let` and `\newcommand` but neither worked. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\cLists{leftmargin=*}
\setlist{\cLists}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Why the close vote? I don't think this is a duplicate of [Defining starred versions of commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4386/2693)

Comment: Use `\expandafter\setlist\expandafter{\cLists}` instead. I think this has to do with the definition of `\setlist` that can take optional arguments.

Comment: @AlanMunn I was confused for a moment. I deleted the automatic coment, but I can't undo my vote.

Comment: @lockstep: Two days and your confusion will be lost. See [Cancel asking to close?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/352/5764)

Comment: @Werner Rather to the fact that `\setlist` expects a list of options and doesn't perform expansion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To appropriately use a control sequence `\cLists` as arguments to `\setlist`, use

```
\expandafter\setlist\expandafter{\cLists}
```

This expands `\cLists` first, before passing it to `\setlist`.