# How to define command with *

Tags: macros, starred-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining starred versions of commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands)

I have some user command:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section{#1}}
```

Now I need to use command:

```
\mysection*{name of section}
```

But this case works bad.
How I must define `\mysection*` command?

Can anybody help me?

This must be some like that:

```
\newcommand{\mysection*}[1]{\section*{#1}}
```

Comment: I would recommend the `xparse` pacakge. However, I am sure that this is  already answered here