# New command and the corresponding star counterpart with xparse

Tags: macros, starred-version, xparse

The following works as expected:

```
\newcommand{\engl}[2]{#1 (en. \textsl{#2})\index{en-ro}{#2}}
```

However, what I want to achieve would be a `*` version of it which only adds to the indices, without the visible text, something like:

```
\newcommand{\engl*}[2]{#1 (en. \textsl{#2})\index{en-ro}{#2}\term{#1!#2}\term{#2!#1}}
```

Of course, this does not work (the pdf is compiled, but with lots of warnings which were not there with the original definition), so I've tried something equivalent with xparse:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\engl{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF#1
    {\index{en-ro}{#1}\term{#1}}
    {#1 (en. \textsl{#2})\index{en-ro}{#2}\term{#1!#2}\term{#2!#1}}%
}
```

which doesn't work either.

How to properly create such a command and its `*` counterpart?

Comment: At least related: [Defining starred versions of commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands)

Answer (score 13):

From the `xparse` 'point of view', a star is an *additional* optional argument. Thus `#1` is a boolean representing 'there is a star', while `#2` and `#3` are the two mandatory arguments. This leads to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\engl}{smm}{%
  #2 (en. \textsl{#3})\index{en-ro}{#3}%
  \IfBooleanT#1
    {\textrm{#2!#3}\textrm{#3!#2}}%
}
\begin{document}

\engl{X}{aaa}

\engl*{X}{aaa}

\end{document}
```

where I've shared code as far as possible and only provided a TRUE case for the presence of a star.

Answer (score 8):

This is tagged [xetex](/questions/tagged/xetex) and [xparse](/questions/tagged/xparse) but doesn't depend on xetex, and you don't really need `xparse` for star forms which are reasonably well supported by latex. I changed `\term` to `\textrm` just so it ran.

Just define the nostar and star forms, then define your top level command to switch between them

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\englnostar}[2]{#1 (en. \textsl{#2})\index{en-ro}{#2}}

\newcommand{\englstar}[2]{#1 (en. \textsl{#2})\index{en-ro}{#2}\textrm{#1!#2}\textrm{#2!#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\engl{\@ifstar\englstar\englnostar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\engl{X}{aaa}



\engl*{X}{aaa}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the two versions would have different number of parameters?

Comment: It would be against the latex syntax guidelines to make the number of arguments depend on a star (or an optional argument) _no_  standard latex command does that. However there is no connection between the two comnands they can have any definition and argument structure. `\engl` itself just looks for a * (not the pther arguments) and then calls one or other command.