# Do starred commands eat up space after them?

Tags: spacing, macros, starred-version

Do starred commands eat up spaces after them, like unstarred ones do? That is, is `\somecommand* nextword` equivalent to `\somecommand*nextword`?

And: Does it depend on the [particular way a starred command is defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/)?

**Edit:** Note that the original version of my question left out me considering only zero-argument commands. I was assuming this, and it was mostly clear (albeit implicit) from the question statement. User @tohecz has written a valuable answer (to the pre-edit version) addressing this detail.

Note that I'm asking about commands with a star at the end of their name (`\somecommand*`), **not** about whether the command was defined using a starred defining command (e.g. with `\newcommand*`).

Comment: This should be fairly easy to test or am I missing something?  Behavior really should be the same as without the `*`, unless the macro was designed to do things differently based on the presence or absence of the `*.`

Comment: @PeterGrill Yeah :-) I was gonna test it but then found that there are a handful of different ways of doing things (e.g. [what's in the UK TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=cmdstar)). I figured someone might already know this already, *if* the answer is method-independent (for the methods that are presently used).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No they don't:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix,xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{suffix,xparse}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycmdA}{\@ifstar
  \mycmdA@star% \mycmd*
  \mycmdA@nostar% \mycmd
}
\newcommand{\mycmdA@star}{A1}
\newcommand{\mycmdA@nostar}{A2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdB}{s}{%
  B\IfBooleanTF{#1}{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\mycmdC}{C1}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\mycmdC*{C2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is \mycmdA and \mycmdA* in one line. \par
Here is \mycmdB and \mycmdB* in one line. \par
Here is \mycmdC and \mycmdC* in one line.
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, see my comment in the tohecz thread.

Answer (score 11):

As the other answers show, they do not. However, the spaces get "eaten" if the macro takes other arguments after `*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section {Hello}
\section* {World!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, TeX ignores all spaces when looking for an argument (unless it is not, which is when an argument is delimited (like optional arguments are):

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1][A]{(#1)}
\foo [abc]    % prints: (abc)
\foo[abc]     % prints: (abc)
\foo [ abc]   % prints: ( abc)
\foo[ abc]    % prints: ( abc)

\def\baz|#1|{(#1)}
\baz |abc|    % prints: (abc)
\baz|abc|     % prints: (abc)
\baz | abc|   % prints: ( abc)
\baz| abc|    % prints: ( abc)
```

Comment: Good point; see my edit to the question statement.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Despite not being what _you_ ask for, it seems to be a consensus here that we treat even the closely-related stuff, in the sense of "wiki-like" approach ;)

Comment: I welcome your answer and I think it belongs here. (Just like other informative edits and *questions*, though some other SE sites have a more rigid approach towards the latter.) But it's also good that I clarified the scope of my question; it'll prevent confusion. More importantly I'd find it weird not to tell you about my edit :-)

Comment: Agreed :) [.](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ha, I've discovered unexpected behavior!! Check out the following: `\mycmdA *`, `\mycmdB *`, `\mycmdC *`. (To actually print a star, the following works: `\mycmdA **`, `\mycmdB **`, `\mycmdC **`.) Is this intentional?

Comment: Oh, my previous comment actually applies to the Werner thread. Let me tell him.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: This is intentional. All spaces after a control sequence is gobbled; grabbing the first `*` is as a result of `\@ifstar`, leaving a final `*` for printing...

Comment: @Werner Good to know, but is this clearly documented for the average user/learner? This is **very** unexpected given that from a LaTeX perspective we think of the starred version as a single command. In all cases where I'd encounter something like `\somecommand *` I'd assume that someone is trying to apply `\somecommand` to the single-token argument `*`.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Perhaps in a similar context you might find it unexpected that `\mycmd{text}` yields **text** if `\newcommand{\mycmd}{\textbf}`, even though `\mycmd` doesn't take any argument...

Comment: @Werner `\textbf` does take an argument, it's just that this fact is obscured through/in LaTeX's definition mechanism.

Comment: @Werner My point is different: We never see a starred command written like this: `\somecommand *`, but always like this: `\somecommand*`. An ordinary user of LaTeX would assume that this is "one command", but in fact it's parsed as a control sequence plus a token. And "commands" never have spaces in them (we think). I hope that it's clear that from a parsing grammar or compiler writer's perspective this doesn't look like good design. And if I hadn't tried it out here, I'd still not know. Perhaps I'm using "command" wrong as a LaTeX-technical term, but that doesn't change my point.

Comment: @LoverofStructure The other option would have been to make `*` a letter, but then I don't want to see people complaining about `\alpha*\beta` not working. As well notice that you can't write `\begin{align *}`

Comment: @tohecz About your last sentence: That's good, but it confirms the lack of internal syntactic consistency. About your first sentence: (1) The other option would have been to pick a different character for inclusion in command names. It's limiting already that control sequences can be only letters. (2) Or (simpler) would be to require people writing `\alpha * \beta`. (3) `\somecommand*\beta` *is* already a problem if `\somecommand` accepts a starred variant and semantically produces some symbol meant to be multiplied to something else (unless you blame the person who wrote that definition).

Comment: @LoverofStructure (1) It's much easier to remember that `*` is _the_ modifier that works in many different situtations. (2) It makes more sense for the macro designers. (3) So `\alpha+\beta` would work but `\alpha*\beta` would not? (4) Vast majority of macros taking `*` take another argument as well, and it very rarely is `*`.

Comment: @tohecz (1), (2), and (4) are not reasons against a design where control sequences don't eat spaces. So many programming languages use obligatory `()` for single-argument functions; the (La)TeX equivalent would be `{}` for single-argument macros. / An alternative would be to terminate a macro-argument sequence with `.` or `;`. / @(3): Every programming language has token sequences that must be circumvented, for example `*` immediately before a variable name in C (dereferencing). Usually certain token sequences must be *avoided*; it's weird that a space inside a command name is *permissible*.

Comment: The problem is that they _are not_ inside a name of a command. The star is _not part of the name_, it is an optional first argument. Notice that TeX is an expansions language (by design), which means that a "function" with 2 arguments can be actually designed as a "function" with one argument that outputs in the stream another "function" with one argument. And since `*` is an argument, why whould it eat spaces? The general problem is that TeX is a typesetting system, so spaces _have to_ be "active" in the sense that they do something more than e.g. in C.

Comment: @tohecz You're are presenting an "argument by legacy constraint"; surely this is more of a "late justification" than a design argument. That `*` should be regarded an optional argument is a useful point of view, but it's not documented well. Whether the design of TeX is modern is an argument for another discussion, but there is no reason to justify the way space characters are presently handled if it has intransparent syntactic consequences. It's better to leave the warning as is, for people to notice and be cautioned, than to defend the status quo as some sort of obvious and natural choice.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Many things are not obvious and natural, in any programming language. Sorry if I present "bad arguments", I'm not a professional "arguer". However, I know many people complaining about different things and having different difficulties in LaTeX, but space between a macro name and the following `*` has never been one of them.

Comment: @tohecz Many of your points are good ones, and all of your input is valued anyways :-) I think it's good for our exchange to be here; it'll serve as good information and documentation for other users.

Answer (score 10):

As other answers have indicated, technically the space dropping is part of the scanning for a command name, and at the primitive TeX level the `*` is not part of the name.

However in LaTeX syntax the star form is always considered a distinct command `\section` and `\section*` are documented as two related commands, not one command that looks ahead to see if there is a `*` or not.

So it is good practice to make the star form have similar behaviour to the non-star form.

In all cases in the base LaTeX format, as far as I can see, the *-command is always used with arguments (like `\section*`) and so any space is skipped at a different stage or occurs at places where a space character will make a space token but won't produce space in the output `\\*`,  `\ProcessOptions*`.

Thus I don't think any standard LaTeX * form of a command would produce white space from a space character after the `*`.

Comment: Or `\tableofcontents*` in `memoir`.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I can't quite follow is the part of the sentence that reads "skipped at a different stage".

Comment: @egreg See my comment to the @tohecz thread. David Carlisle's point that in TeX the `*` is not part of the name shows in those examples. Parsing irregularities in (La)TeX are imho an area that needs improvement. (LaTeX 3?)

Comment: @LoverofStructure in `\section {hello}` the space is never tokenized it is lost while scanning the command name. in `\section* {hello}` the space is seen and tokenized but space tokens before mandatory arguments are dropped while scanning for macro arguments "a different stage"

Answer (score 5):

Only control words eat space after them! Control words are macros begin with the escape character `\` and followed by one or more letters.