# If I redefine a command that has a starred variant, will that always disable the starred variant?

Tags: macros, tex-core, starred-version

If I redefine a command that has a starred variant, will this **always** effectively disable the starred variant, as a side effect of redefining the unstarred variant?

A related question: [Do starred commands eat up space after them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97650/14996) (The information contained therein strongly suggests a "yes", but it'll be good to hear a confirmation from an expert.)

Notes:

- This question was meant to be generic.
- I mean the redefining act per se. That is, let's assume that I might not include a starred variant in my redefinition.
- Some examples I had in mind (for which it would actually make sense to redefine the starred version with them, unless one is short of time and doesn't need to for one's local document):

  - I was thinking of redefining `\hspace` or `\vspace` to be visible (for draft compilation runs).
  - In some earlier drafts of documents of mine, `\chapter` was redefined to contain a call to `\pagestyle`.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Less short answer: it depends on how you do the redefinition. Can you give a couple of examples of what you're redefining? If not, the question seems to be too generic.

Comment: @egreg Not sure this will change any answers, but I've added some examples so that the question isn't too abstract.

Comment: For making glue "visible", you can try the very clever `visual-lua-debug` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are basically two ways of defining commands with a *-variant.

### Traditional way

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar\@sfoo\@foo}
\newcommand{\@sfoo}{something for the *-version}
\newcommand{\@foo}{something for the plain version}
```

where `\@sfoo` and `\@foo` may have arguments; the names are arbitrary, of course: they are two other commands. Many variations are encountered; here's an example:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar{\@tempswatrue\@foo}{\@tempswafalse\@foo}}
\newcommand{\@foo}{%
  \if@tempswa
     we're with the *-version
  \else
     we're with the plain version
  \fi}

\newcommand\chapter{%
   <code that's irrelevant for the example>%
   \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

In the second example, the lookup for a following * is delegated to `\secdef`.

In many cases, `\newcommand{\foo}{...}` is changed into `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{...}` to avoid problems with `\foo` in moving arguments; the auxiliary macros `\@sfoo` or `\@foo` can be still defined with `\newcommand` (or `\def`, if one prefers).

### `xparse` way

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{s...}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {Code for the *-version}
     {Code for the plain version}%
  }
```

where `...` stands for other argument types, possibly none.

### Redefining

If you have `\foo` defined in one of those ways, saying

```
\renewcommand{\foo}{bar}
```

will of course remove any possibility that `\foo*` works as before, because the new `\foo` doesn't check for a * following it, which is in any case the key for a *-variant to work.

Thus, if you want to redefine a command with a *-variant, you should know how it was defined in the first place. In the most common case, with `\@ifstar` choosing between two different commands, just redefine the one you need, so `\@foo` or `\@sfoo`. The same applies for the `\chapter` example, where you can work on `\@schapter` or `\@chapter`. It would be more difficult in the `\if@tempswa` case, but one should know what the intention is.

If you want to redefine `\section`, then you find yourself in a more complicated situation, then the problem is more difficult; the definition is usually in terms of `\@startsection` which is the macro doing the `\@ifstar` test, so the approaches outlined above don't work. In this case a simple way out is to say

```
\let\latexsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\latexsection*}{\mynewsection}}
```

and to define `\mynewsection` for the "non *" case, probably in terms of `\latexsection`.

Watch out, though, and always check how the command is defined: in case of doubt, the `\let` should be replaced with `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package.

Redefining `xparse` based commands should be done with `\RenewDocumentCommand` and the proper argument types. *Don't* use `\let` or `\LetLtxMacro` in this case.

---

Just for fun, here are some patches that make glue inserted with `\hspace`, `\vspace` or `\addvspace` "visible". However they are not guaranteed to always work and to give the same breaks.

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@hspace}{\hskip}{\leaders\hrule\hskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@hspacer}{\hskip}{\leaders\hrule\hskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\@vspace}{\vskip#1}{\leaders\vrule\vskip#1}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\@vspacer}{\nobreak\vskip}{\nobreak\leaders\vrule\vskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\addvspace}{\vskip}{\leaders\vrule\vskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\@xaddvskip}{\vskip\@tempskipb}{\leaders\vrule\vskip\@tempskipb}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Which of the two ways does the `suffix` way (= the third method I'm aware of) of defining a starred variant fall into?

Comment: @LoverofStructure `suffix` uses a completely different method, which I'm not expert of.

Answer (score 17):

It depends how you redefine the command. At the TeX level there is no such thing as a starred variant the base command just looks ahead for a star and acts accordingly. So if you redefine it such that it still looks ahead for the star then it will do so, otherwise it won't.

Alternatvely you can save the old command of course.

Here the `\section` commands use the new `\fbox` definition but `\oldsection*` works as before.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldsection\section

\def\section#1{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}
One

\oldsection*{xyz}

One two

\section{zzz}
One Two three

\end{document}
```

Or this version which makes the same output but allows you to use `\section` for the new definition and `\section*` for the old star form.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldsection\section

\makeatletter
\def\section{\@ifstar{\oldsection*}\fbox}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{abc}
One

\section*{xyz}

One two

\section{zzz}
One Two three

\end{document}
```

---

A comment on the examples that you added. Redefining `\hspace` and `\vspace` to be visible without changing the document spacing is hard (probably impossible in general) so whatever redefinition you had in mind, the extra work of adding `\@ifstar` and redefining the * form at the same time would not be your main problem.

For redefining chapter, most definitions of chapter (eg the ones in `book` and `report`) already have a `thispagestyle` but ignoring that you could probably just put your definition at the front and leave the old definition still looking for `*`:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{foo}\oldchapter}
```

(egreg points out correctly that in real life you can't ignore the fact there is already a `\thispagestyle` as the existing one will overwrite the one added)

Comment: About your last point: this might be relevant for `memoir`.

Answer (score 10):

For plain macros, the starred and unstarred variants are actually the same macro in which the `*` plays the role of an optional argument; the `xparse` mechanics that egreg describes make this much clearer.  However, for *environments*, the starred and unstarred variants are completely different: there are actually separate environments called, say, `equation` and `equation*` (from amsmath), and redefining `equation` will do absolutely nothing to `equation*`.  The reason for this is that while a starred macro will do something like

```
\def\macro{\@ifnextchar*{<yes>}{<no>}}
```

a starred environment actually has the star in its name.  Recall that an environment is actually a pair of macros, so:

```
\def\equation{...}
\def\endequation{...}
```

and therefore for `equation*` we would have, if `*` were made a letter:

```
\catcode`*=11
\def\equation*{...}
\def\endequation*{...}
```

However, the way it's actually done is that `\begin` just feeds its argument to `\csname...\endcsname`, which means that environment names can be much weirder than macro names:

```
\begin{equation*} --> \csname equation*\endcsname
\end{equation*}   --> \csname endequation*\endcsname
% plus other stuff, of course
```

So for environments, the relation between the starred and unstarred variants is a matter of *convention* that is not enforced by the code, while for macros, in fact, the starred variant is created by the expansion/parsing process.

Comment: +1 for a valuable contribution (environments as opposed to commands)