# Create \eqref* (\eqref without link, i.e. starred eqref)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, equations, amsmath, italic

I want to create a command `\eqref*`, which is the same like `\eqref`, but without a clickable link.
There are similar commands for `\ref` (`\ref*`) and `\autoref` (`\autoref*`) which achieve this behaviour, but not for `\eqref`.

```
\newcommand{\myeqref}[1]{(\ref*{#1})}
```

Would work, but I don't like the naming, and there is an additional problem: `\eqref` writes numbers upright even in italic math environment, `\ref` doesn't do this.

Any help is appreciated.

[ Edit: for search engines: eqref, eqref*, eqrefstar, starred eqref, eqrefasterisk, asterisked eqref, eqref star, eqref asterisk ]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a solution that borrows from Joseph Wright's `LaTeX3` solution to [Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands)

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldeqref\eqref
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\eqref{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF#1%
  {\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#2}}}}% If a star is seen
  {\oldeqref{#2}}%                 If no star is seen
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a=b \label{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
  \item starred version: \eqref*{1} 
  \item unstarred version: \eqref{1}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#2}}}` instead of `\oldeqref`

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, as I defined `\Eqref` instead of a starred `\eqref`. I just copied the definition of `\eqref` from `amsmath.sty`, and added a `*` to the `\ref` used there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a=b \label{1}
\end{equation}

\Eqref{1} \eqref{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands

this could help also.

Comment: @oerpli Yeah, I know there are a couple of those. I was just too lazy ...

Answer (score 4):

Solution: Thanks to Torbjørn T. and oerpli, here's a(nother) solution:

```
\makeatletter
\def\eqref{\@ifstar\@eqref\@@eqref}
\def\@eqref#1{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\def\@@eqref#1{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

And a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\eqref{\@ifstar\@eqref\@@eqref}
\def\@eqref#1{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\def\@@eqref#1{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=b \label{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
A standard ref is italic in math mode: \ref{1} \\
A standard ref* is also italic in math mode: \ref*{1} \\
An eqref is upright: \eqref{1}\\
And so is the new eqref*: \eqref*{1} 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```