# Differences between \newcommand, \NewDocumentCommand and \DeclareRobustCommand

Tags: macros, xparse, latex-base

What are the main differences between `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`?
Could you answer me giving exhaustive examples, please?

I already read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195883/different-result-using-newcommand-and-newdocumentcommand) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands-macro?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I'd like to know more.

Comment: See also: [macros - Always use \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98152/always-use-newdocumentcommand-instead-of-newcommand)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`\newcommand`** is the good'ol command for defining user-level commands in LaTeX: it allows you to make a long (`\newcommand`) or short ([`\newcommand*`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/134574)) command, and allows you to have a command with an optional argument and give it a default.

On top of that, you can use `\newcommand*` instead, and the commands will be short macros (they will error if there is a `\par` in the argument).

Commands defined with `\newcommand` will be robust if they take an optional argument, and will be expandable otherwise.

---

**`\DeclareRobustCommand`** is a companion to `\newcommand`:  it makes *every* command defined with it robust, including ones that don't take optional arguments.  `\newcommand` making commands with optional arguments robust is a slightly more recent feature ([end of 1995](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews04.pdf#section*.5)), and `\DeclareRobustCommand` predates that (added mid-1994).

You will use `\DeclareRobustCommand` when your command is not expandable and it's supposed to be used in moving arguments (for example section titles or captions).  If your command should be expandable, you *cannot* use `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Since 2015, LaTeX provides `\MakeRobust`.  Doing `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo ...` has exactly the same effect as `\newcommand\foo ...` then `\MakeRobust\foo`.

---

**`\NewDocumentCommand`** is (along with its expandable counterpart **`\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`**) kind of the successor to `\newcommand`:  they allow you to define commands with different combinations of mandatory (`m` and `r`) and optional arguments (`d` and `o`), starred versions of a command (`s`), different combinations of long ([`+`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/134574)) and short arguments.  It also allows you to pre-process an argument before passing it to the command (using `>`).

Different from `\newcommand`, commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are *always* robust, and ones defined with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` are *always* expandable (as long as the code in them is also expandable).

---

In the past, package authors only had `\newcommand` (and `\DeclareRobustCommand`, which is roughly the same thing) to define user interfaces, and if  that wasn't enough for whatever reason, then the programmer had to do the parsing manually.  `\NewDocumentCommand`, on the other hand, has a much more complex parsing machinery that goes *far* beyond what `\newcommand` provides, so it is the recommended way to create user-level commands (see [this blog post](https://www.texdev.net/2020/08/20/newdocumentcommand-versus-newcommand-versus) on that matter).

Nowadays, it is recommended to use `\newcommand` only when you want the simple interface it provides, and you have a performance-critical application (the features of `\NewDocumentCommand` come at a cost), or when you are using a command as a simple text substitution ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503752/134574)).

On the technical side, `\newcommand` is also very different from `\NewDocumentCommand`.  Suppose we are defining a command `\foo`. `\newcommand` just defines `\foo` to look for an optional argument, and then `\\foo` to actually grab them (or just `\foo` if there is no optional), and that's that.  When defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\foo` is actually just a wrapper around internal LaTeX macros that will do the parsing of the arguments, and then pass them to the actual definition of the command stored in `\foo code`.

---

P.S.:  Also note that while `\newcommand` and `\NewDocumentCommand` check if the command being defined already exist (trying to protect you from shooting yourself on the foot), `\DeclareRobustCommand` doesn't, and will overwrite existing commands.  There is also `\renewcommand` and `\RenewDocumentCommand` in case you want to redefine something.  There is also `provide` versions of both, which only create the definition if there isn't one yet (kind of a "fallback version" of a command), and there is also `\DeclareDocumentCommand` that always creates the definition (not recommended), but no matching `\declarecommand`.

Comment: actually `\DeclareRobustCommand`  is 2e as well

Comment: The LaTeX2.09 way used to be `\def\LaTeX{\protect\pLaTeX}\def\pLaTeX{...}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh! Not sure where I got that from. I'll fix, thanks!