# Defining a macro in which \emph behaves differently

Tags: macros, emphasis

I want to declare a macro `\myemph` which typesets its argument in italics. When `\emph` is used in `\myemph`, it should use boldface. But when `\emph` is used outside of `\myemph`, it should still use italics:

```tex
\emph{italic, \emph{upright}} % as usual
\myemph{italic, \emph{bold and italic}} % new command
```

(For the moment, I do not care about nested `\emph` in `\myemph`.)

I have attempted to declare the macro below. This seems to work fine. However, I'm getting weird errors when I use this in section or chapter titles:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\org@emph\emph
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bfemph}{\bfseries}
\newcommand{\myemph}[1]{\textit{\RenewCommandCopy\emph\bfemph#1\RenewCommandCopy\emph\org@emph}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myemph{italic, \emph{bold and italic}} % works

\section{\myemph{Section}} % error

\end{document}
```

(I'm not sure if there's any benefit to defining `\bfemph` over just using `\textbf`.)

The error I get is: `Argument of \@sect has an extra }`. How can I define `\myemph` so that it also works in this environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change what `\emph` does by using `\DeclareEmphSequence{<font change command list>}`.  You can restrict that to your `\myemph` command by enclosing that in a group:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myemph}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \DeclareEmphSequence{\itshape,\bfseries}%
    \emph{#1}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\myemph{italic, \emph{bold and italic}} % works

\section{\myemph{Section}} % error

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Keelan Usually when a nontrivial macro is used in section titles or figure captions and it breaks, the solution is to define that macro with `\DeclareRobustCommand` (I wrote something about that earlier today [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619849/134574)).  Your `\myemph` macro is not expandable, but writing to the .toc file forces it to expand and it breaks.  Making it robust solves the problem