# Macro to add starred version of command

Tags: macros, starred-version

How can one write a meta-macro that adds a starred version to a command?

Intended use would be along the lines of

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{foo is #1}
\addstarred\foo[2]{foo is #1, bar is #2}
```

Comment: Something like `\WithSuffix`? Than this answer can be usefull: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4388/3061

Comment: Could you maybe explain how the `\WithSuffix` command works?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how it works internally. But a possible use case is shown in the linked answer.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Maybe you want to turn it into a question about how `\WithSuffix` works. It does quite similarly to what you propose, by the way. The code is `\WithSuffix\newcommand\foo*[2]{foo is #1, bar is #2}` (with `\usepackage{suffix}`).

Comment: I do not actually ask how to define starred versions, I can do that quickly enough with three separate commands. Being a programmer, I am curious how to do macro-writing macros in LaTeX. And I figured this is an interesting case that is actually useful.

Comment: @Nicolas Are we to assume that `\foo` is defined before the use of `\addstarred\foo`? Do we have to allow for LaTeX 'robust' commands (I assume we do)? What is expected if `\foo` is redefined after `\addstarred` or if `\addstarred` is applied multiple times?

Comment: The only way that seemed possible _to me_ was to assume that `\foo` was already defined and to add the `\@ifstar` switch to its definition. I have mostly asked to find out whether there are other, more natural possibilities. The answer "from the Book" would probably be a simple `\newcommand\foo*` that is impossible to break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method is already available with the package `suffix` by David Kastrup. Needless to say, it's full of clever tricks.

You can say

```
\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{foo is #1}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\foo*[2]{foo is #1, bar is #2}
```

and it may be instructive to see how the objective is achieved.

If we do `\show\foo` after the second instruction, we find

```
> \foo=\protected macro:
->\WSF@suffixcheck \foo .
```

so we learn that `suffix` requires e-TeX (not a problem nowadays) and redefines `\foo` to mean `\WSF@suffixcheck\foo`. So we add `\makeatletter` and try `\show\WSF@suffixcheck`, getting

```
> \WSF@suffixcheck=macro:
#1->\begingroup \def \reserved@a {#1}\futurelet \reserved@b \WSF@suffixcheckii
```

so the argument is saved in `\reserved@a` and

```
\futurelet\reserved@b\WSF@suffixcheckii
```

is executed. This makes `\reserved@b` to be equivalent to the token that follows `\WSF@suffixcheckii`. If the call is

```
\foo{foo}
```

then `\reserved@b` will be `\bgroup`; if the call is

```
\foo*{foo}{bar}
```

then `\reserved@b` will be `*`. Now we need to know what `\WSF@suffixcheckii` does:

```
> \WSF@suffixcheckii=macro:
->\ifcsname \expandafter \SuffixName \reserved@a \reserved@b \endcsname
  \expandafter \WSF@suffixcheckiii \else \expandafter \WSF@suffixcheckiv \fi .
```

OK, let's see what happens in the `\foo{foo}` case: `\reserved@a` expands to `\foo`, while `\reserved@b` is `\bgroup` (unexpandable), so TeX is first presented with

```
\ifcsname\SuffixName\foo\reserved@b\endcsname
```

and `\SuffixName` is defined by

```
> \SuffixName=\long macro:
#1->WSF:\string #1 \meaning .
```

so the next step is

```
\ifcsname WSF:\string\foo \meaning\reserved@b\endcsname
```

and we finally get

```
\ifcsname WSF:\foo begin-group character {\endcsname
```

where all characters have category code 12 (but spaces have 10). In the `\foo*{foo}{bar}` case we would get

```
\ifcsname WSF:\foo the character *\endcsname
```

The command `\csname WSF:\foo begin-group character {\endcsname` is not defined, so the false branch is followed, that is

```
\expandafter \WSF@suffixcheckiv \fi
```

which simply leaves

```
\WSF@suffixcheckiv{foo}
```

in the input stream. Now `\show\WSF@suffixcheckiv` gives

```
> \WSF@suffixcheckiv=macro:
->\expandafter \endgroup \csname \expandafter \NoSuffixName \reserved@a \endcsname .
```

so the group previously opened is closed but first

```
\csname \expandafter \NoSuffixName \reserved@a \endcsname
```

is formed. Recall that `\reserved@a` expands to `\foo`, so we get

```
\csname \NoSuffixName \foo \endcsname
```

and `\NoSuffixName` is

```
> \NoSuffixName=macro:
->WSF:\string .
```

so finally we obtain

```
\csname WSF:\string\foo\encsname
```

OK, let's issue `\expandafter\show\csname WSF:\string\foo\endcsname`:

```
> \WSF:\foo=\long macro:
#1->foo is #1.
```

that is, this complicated macro is a copy of the original `\foo`.

In the case of `\foo*{foo}{bar}` we'd have

```
\ifcsname WSF:\foo the character *\endcsname
```

but in this case this *is* defined; indeed

```
\expandafter\show\csname WSF:\string\foo\space the character *\endcsname
```

produces

```
> \WSF:\foo the character *=\long macro:
#1#2->foo is #1, bar is #2.
```

so this macro with a complicated name is what you have defined as `*`-variant.

Almost any token can be used as a suffix, with this package. But the essential idea is no different from what you have devised; the protections against overwriting possible existing macro names are better. What the package does when

```
\WithSuffix\newcommand\foo*[2]{foo is #1, bar is #2}
```

is processed is

1. Save the original `\foo` command under

   ```
   \csname WSF:\string\foo\endcsname
   ```

   (if this already exists because of a preceding `\WithSuffix` applied to `\foo` this step is of course omitted)
2. Save the new definition under

   ```
   \csname WSF:\string\foo\space the character *\endcsname
   ```
3. Use the abstract interface described above to choose among different suffixes.

Comment: Great explanation. If I understood the method well, this basically turns the simplistic `if next-token == '*'` into a `switch`-like construct selecting whatever command has been defined for a given suffix.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, and in a clever way for transforming the suffix into a string and avoiding expansion problems. However I much prefer the `xparse` method.

Answer (score 4):

My own attempt at a solution is below, with improvements kindly provided by @egreg and @DavidCarlisle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addstarred[1]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname\string#1@nostar\endcsname#1%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\@ifstar\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1@star\endcsname\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1@nostar\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\string#1@star\endcsname%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\foo[1]{foo is #1}
\addstarred\foo[2]{foo is #1, bar is #2}

\begin{document}
    \foo{red} --- \foo*{red}{green}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE output]

Explanation:

- A copy of the current definition of the command `\foo` is stored as `\\foo@nostar`.
- The command `\foo` is redefined to check for a star and call either `\\foo@star` or `\\foo@nostar`.
  This is done with `edef` so that the constructed token names can be expanded in place and not every time the command is invoked.
- A `\newcommand` for `\\foo@star` is started and will take the rest of the definition as follows `\addstarred\foo`.

Comment: Storing `\foo` in `\\foo` *will* definitely conflict if `\foo` had been defined to have an optional argument.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Maybe the name of the commands should have been a little less obvious.

Comment: I have since edited the answer to be an epsilon amount less obvious.

Comment: You need a `%` on each of the lines of the definition that doesn't have a `%` and do not need a `%` on the line that has one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the `%` to all lines now. I assumed that, since this should appear in the preamble, extra line breaks would not matter.

Comment: newcommands don't _have_ to appear in the preamble (and there was a time that saving three bytes mattered:-) for similar reasons I'd do `\edef#1{\@ifstar\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1@star\endcsname\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1@nostar\endcsname}}%`  so that the defined command just had two tokens after ifstar with the new command names made at define time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, these tips are the exact reason why I asked this question.