# How do I construct a command name containing a star?

Tags: xparse, starred-version

I defined the following command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \displayls {s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textls*[250]{#2}}{\textls[250]{#2}}%
}
```

I would like to refactor the definition to remove the duplication.

I can make a trivial version:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \displayls {s m}{%
  \csname textls\endcsname[250]{#2}%
}
```

If I then try to process the star argument, I get into trouble. I tried:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \displayls {s m}{%
  \csname textls\IfBooleanTF{#1}{*}{}\endcsname[250]{#2}%
}
```

But this does not work for the `*`-form; it produces:

[image]

Here is the test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \displayls {s m}{%
  % (One of the definitions above)
}

\begin{document}
\displayls{foo}
\displayls*{foo}
\end{document}
```

I tried adding `\expandafter` before `\csname`, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Related: [Defining starred versions of commands (`*` macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4386/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just duplicate `\textls`; or use `\exp_last_unbraced:Nf` (but I wouldn't bother to).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayls}{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textls*}{\textls}[250]{#2}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\displaylsvar{s m}
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \textls \IfBooleanT{#1}{*} [250] {#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\displayls{foo}
\displayls*{foo}

\displaylsvar{foo}
\displaylsvar*{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for information about your attempt. If you call `\textls*` it's *two* tokens, namely `\textls` and `*`; to the contrary, `\csname textls*\endcsname` constructs a single token (undefined, so treated like `\relax`).

Also, here's the definition of `\textls` by `microtype`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\textls{%
  \@ifstar{\let\MT@ls@adjust@\MT@ls@adjust@empty\MT@textls}%
          {\let\MT@ls@adjust@\MT@ls@adjust@relax\MT@textls}%
}
```

I see no much point in avoiding the duplication in the suggested simple version.