# Problem about the argument of macro defined by \def

Tags: tex-core

I construct a macro named `\mymacro`, and this macro would be used in two ways:

first: `\mymacro`, which would typeset 1

second:`\mymacro*`, which would typeset 2

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\def\mymacro#1{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{*}}{2}{1}}
with star: \mymacro* some text\\ % That is ok.
without star: \mymacro some text % "s" of "some" lost
\end{document}
```

From the attached typeset you can see that the first charactor `s` of the word `some` is lost in the version of `without star`. Why?

I know `\mymacro{}` is a solution, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to just use `\mymacro` only.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining starred versions of commands (\* macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands-macro) (But I must admit than I prefer the non-accepted answers.)

Comment: With `\def\mymacro#1{...stuff...}` you define a macro that takes on argument. It will always try and absorb an argument. When you use it as `\mymacro*` the star gets absorbed as argument, but when you say `\mymacro some more text`, `\mymacro` grabs the following `s` as its argument. The classical way to define starred versions uses `\@ifstar`, but with new LaTeX you can use the (formerly `xparse`) `\IfBooleanTF` of `\NewDocumentCommand`'s `s` type.

Comment: @moewe Would you show me an exmple how to use `@\ifstar?

Comment: Just follow campa's link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4389/35864