# Using \protect to generalise definitions of starred commands?

Tags: starred-version, protected-macro, def

[This very helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4389/164050) led me to define my own starred commands. However, in order to use my commands in, for example, headings, after a round of strange almost frightening thoughts, I managed to arrive at the following (MWE):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\testone{\@ifstar\@dothis\@@dothat}
\def\testtwo{\protect\@ifstar\protect\@dothis\protect\@@dothat}
\def\@dothis#1{#1}
\def\@@dothat#1{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\testone{abc}} % does not work
\testone{abc} % works
\section{\testtwo{abc}} % works
\testtwo{abc} % works
\end{document}
```

I am still struggling to percolate `TeX`'s expansion mechanisms and, hence, would be thankful for an answer about why my definition `\test...` requires these `\protect`s to work in headings? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and friends with an `s`-type (starred) argument?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. No, actually not. Haven't even been aware of these. Are these (La)TeX primitives and working with LuaTeX as well?

Comment: These are part of newer LaTeX kernels. See `usrguide.pdf` current version for more information.

Comment: Ah, cheers. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

`\protect` is wrong in those places.

If you want to make `\testtwo` robust, you need to use

```
\newcommand{\testtwo}{}% for safety against redefining
\DeclareRobustCommand{\testtwo}{\@ifstar\@dothis\@@dothat}
```

But it's simpler to use `\NewDocumentCommand`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% there is a *
    called #1 with *%
  }{% no star
    called #1 without *%
  }%
}
```

See [`texdoc usrguide`](https://texdoc.org/serve/usrguide/0) for more information about `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Thx, @egreg, works smoothly. The `usrguide` helps me to revise my "old" LaTeX practices.